# Android SurfaceTexture, video on Sphere, OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, video, geometry, opengl-es-2.0, android-mediaplayer

Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see I have 2 problem.

**1) The sphere render is upside down**

**2) Video is not well wrapped around the sphere.** - SOLVED

In details:

1) The problem is strange but I think is caused by the MediaPlayer of Android and its coordinate system. With an image I haven't this issue. So what will be the solution? Of course I can rotate the sphere but this could cause others problem in the future.

2) The video resolution, and size of the video are't the problems. An image with the same size of the video is correctly wrapped around the sphere. So There aren't bug in the UV calculations. - SOLVED

There is something about MediaPlayer that I don't know.
Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Edit:

Second problem solved. It was necessary to repeat the texture after binding:

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: Hi, I also got this problem "Video is not well wrapped around the sphere." Please let me know how did you solve that? I tried this---

   'gl.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL10.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL10.GL_REPEAT);'

Answer (score 0):

Textures in OpenGL load from bottom up not top down (or something like that).
An easy (possibly?) way to fix this is to change the UV mapping of your sphere to be flipped. I say "possibly" as I don't know what if you made the sphere or if you downloaded it.

Comment: Or you can mirror the v-coordinate in the fragment shader, if that's easier than changing the original texture coordinates.